# how can i ensure each user correctly match their own request?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

My question is as follows:

When integrating Spring WebFlux with Spring Security, and retrieving user IDs by parsing tokens from 
the ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext() context, how does it ensure that each user's request 
corresponds to its own context and avoids mismatches, especially when multiple users are accessing the 
same endpoint simultaneously?

the code show as bellow:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", produces = "application/json")
    public Flux<Result<String>> upload(@RequestPart("file") FilePart filePart) {
        return getUserId()
                .publishOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic())
                .flatMapMany(userId -> filePart.content()
                        .buffer()
                        .flatMap(dataBuffers -> {
                            int totalLength = dataBuffers.stream()
                                    .mapToInt(DataBuffer::readableByteCount)
                                    .sum();
                            byte[] bytes = new byte[totalLength];
                            int offset = 0;
                            for (DataBuffer dataBuffer : dataBuffers) {
                                int length = dataBuffer.readableByteCount();
                                dataBuffer.read(bytes, offset, length);
                                offset += length;
                                DataBufferUtils.release(dataBuffer);
                            }
                            log.info("userId {} received {} file ", userId,filePart.filename());
                            SongCommand.AddSongResource addSongResource = new SongCommand.AddSongResource(userId, filePart.filename(), bytes);
                            CompletionStage<EntityResponse> response = songService.uploadResource(addSongResource);
                            return Mono.fromCompletionStage(response)
                                    .map(entityResponse -> switch (entityResponse) {
                                         case EntityResponse.CommandProcessed _ ->
                                          Result.success("upload successful");
                                         case EntityResponse.CommandRejectedWithEx commandRejectedWithEx ->
                                          Result.fail(STR."upload failed commandRejectedWithEx.error().getMessage()}");
                                         case EntityResponse.CommandRejected commandRejected ->
                                          Result.fail(commandRejected.error().name());
                                         default ->  Result.fail("not support");
                                     });
                        }));
    }


  protected Mono<String> getUserId()  {
        return ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                .map(context -> {
                    Authentication authentication = context.getAuthentication();
                    String principal = (String) authentication.getDetails();
                    return authenticationService.parseTokenForSubject(principal);
                });

    }
```

As shown in the code above, when multiple users access the upload method simultaneously, there are two 
main parameters: one is obtained from **ReactiveSecurityContextHolder.getContext()** and the other is 
obtained from **@RequestPart("file")**. Since they both execute asynchronously, is there a possibility 
of mismatching user data? I am a newcomer who is practicing using reactive frameworks and does not 
understand their underlying logic.

thanks for your answer.